# mysql syntax error on performing a ranking query 

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

i want to perform a ranking query but i'm not sure what is the right syntax 
here is my query:

```
  static public function sortranks(){
    global $db;
    $sql ="TRUNCATE TABLE `ranking`";
    $db->query($sql);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `ranking` (`user_id`) VALUES 
    ( SELECT `employe_id` FROM `rates_employe` WHERE `status` = '0' ORDER BY rawpoint DESC ) ";
    $db->query($sql);

    $sql = "UPDATE  rates_employe , ranking  SET rates_employe.rank = ranking.rank WHERE 
    rates_employe.employe_id = ranking.user_id ";
    $db->query($sql);
    echo 'ok';
    exit;
  }
```

i keep getting syntax error when i run this query

> Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SELECT `employe_id` FROM `rates_employe` WHERE
>   `status` = '0' ORDER BY rawpoint ' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute the queries one by one, instead of joining them together.

Change the `.=` string concatenation with a simple assignment, and after assigning each query, execute it. Such as:

```
 $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE ranking";
 $db->query($sql);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `ranking`(`user_id`) VALUES ..."; 
 $db->query($sql);
```

Also remove VALUES from the query:

> INSERT INTO `ranking` (`user_id`) 
>       ( SELECT `employe_id` FROM `rates_employe` WHERE `status` = '0' ORDER BY rawpoint DESC )

Sorry if I sound pedantic, but in English `Employee` is spelt with two `e` at the end of the word.

Comment: i've updated my answer, you're using the wrong syntax for INSERT ... SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Try running each queries separately:

```
static public function sortranks(){
    global $db;
    $sql ="TRUNCATE TABLE ranking";
    $db->query($sql);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `ranking`(`user_id`) VALUES 
    ( SELECT `employe_id` FROM `rates_employe` WHERE `status` = '0' ORDER BY `rawpoint` DESC ) ";
    $db->query($sql);

    $sql = "UPDATE  rates_employe , ranking  SET rates_employe.rank = ranking.rank WHERE 
    rates_employe.employe_id = ranking.user_id ";

    $db->query($sql);
    echo 'done';
    exit;
  }
```